# prosilica calibration freezes during calibration step

Tags: ros, prosilica-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have any experience calibrating the prosilica camera on the PR2. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrating%20the%20PR2%27s%20Cameras#Prosilica_Camera) but the calibration process tends to freeze up on me.

Setup:

1. PR2 is plugged into the basestation. Ran this whole process from the basestation as well.
2. v1.0.0 of pr2_calibration on the robot.

What I did:

1. Ran: roslaunch pr2_calibration_launch calibrate_prosilica.launch
2. Moved around the checkerboard until the 'Calibrate' button showed up.
3. Clicked on 'Calibrate'
4. Nothing happens for at least a half hour.....'top' tells me that the cameracalibration process takes %86 of the CPU.
5. I eventually kill it.

What am I doing wrong? Am I not waiting long enough?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11252/prosilica-calibration-freezes-during-calibration-step-/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it turns out, it just needed more time to run. I left it overnight and by the time I came in this morning it completed, and the 'save' and 'commit' buttons were displayed.

Lesson learned: Calibration can take a while. Be patient.

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-09-21**:
Yikes. For the record, camera_calibration has been significantly overhauled in ROS Electric, and should be much faster.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-21**:
updated the wiki, thanks for the report.